# OpenCsv's CsvWriter Out of memory in Java heap when exporting large csv file from database query, is there something wrong with my implementation?

Tags: java, opencsv, csvwriter

I want to export a large amount of records from a csv file. Previously I have implemented using OpenCsv's CsvWriter to load one line into memory each time I write into csv. It did alleviate the problem abit but with even larger amount of records I am still having issues with out of memory.

For now I implemented pagination of database records as a workaround but the out of memory error is in the CsvWriter object.

Here is my implementation (ignore my horrible code):

```
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public void getExtremelyLargeLogFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws ParseException, SQLException {
        SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
        session.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
        
        int batch = 0; 
        
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String fileName = "log_" + sdf.format(new Date());
        List<Log> list = // some query like 'select * from table limit 10000 offset 10000*batch;
        String[] titleName = new String[] { "No.", "Modules", "System activities", "Event status",

        buildCsvLineList(response, list, titleName, fileName, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", batch);
        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            batch++; 
            list = // some query like 'select * from table limit 10000 offset 10000*batch;
            buildCsvLineList(response, list, titleName, fileName, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", batch);
        }

        session.commit();
        session.clearCache();   
        session.close();
    }

    private void buildCsvLineList(HttpServletResponse response, List<Logs> logs, String[] titleName,
            String fileName, String pattern, int batch) {
        OutputStream out = null;
        CSVWriter csvWriter = null;

        try {

            out = response.getOutputStream();
            csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out),
                    ',',
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    '\\',
                    System.lineSeparator());

            String lastFileName = fileName + ".csv";
            response.setContentType("application/msexcel;charset=UTF-8");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(lastFileName, "UTF-8"));
            if (batch == 0) {
            csvWriter.writeNext(titleName);
            }

            for (Logs log : logs) {
                 // some implementation 
                csvWriter.writeNext(line.toArray(new String[0]));
                csvWriter.flush();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Export csv exception, errorMessage:{}", e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {

            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Export Csv exception! errorMessage:{}", e.getMessage());
                }

            }

            if (csvWriter != null) {
                try {
                    csvWriter.flush();
                    csvWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Export Csv exception! errorMessage:{}", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.springframework.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.addBuffer(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:304)
        at org.springframework.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.write(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper$ResponseServletOutputStream.write(ContentCachingResponseWrapper.java:230)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:234)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:132)
        at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:142)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:223)
        at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
        at com.opencsv.CSVWriter.writeNext(CSVWriter.java:91)
        at com.opencsv.AbstractCSVWriter.writeNext(AbstractCSVWriter.java:76)
        at com.opencsv.ICSVWriter.writeNext(ICSVWriter.java:162)
```

Hence I would like to ask what is wrong with my implementation, if it seems that the entire result set is still being written into csvWriter object? In the long run we would like to implement streaming.

Edit: The filter code. This is a custom filter that will get the request and response body for logging purposes. After this ApplicationFilterChain will do further processing

```
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain; 
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException; 
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j; 
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter; 
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper; import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

@Slf4j 
@Component 

public class LogFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final int MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH = 2000;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (request.getRequestURI().matches("(?i).*csv.*") ) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

    String requestBody = getStringValue(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(),
            request.getCharacterEncoding());
    String responseBody = null;

    if (!request.getRequestURI().matches("(?i).*csv.*") || response.getStatus() / 100 != 2) {
        responseBody = getStringValue(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray(),
                response.getCharacterEncoding());
    }

        log.info("Client IP: " + clientIp);
        log.info("Finished processing request: {}  {}", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
        log.info("Query String: " + request.getQueryString());

        // log headers
        log.info("Headers: ");
        request.getHeaderNames().asIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(headerName -> log.info("    {}: {}", headerName, request.getHeader(headerName)));

        log.info("Response Code: " + response.getStatus());


        // if requestBody is > 1000 characters, only print the first 1000 characters and append a "..."
        if (requestBody.length() > MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) {
            requestBody = requestBody.substring(0, MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) + "...[omitted " + (requestBody.length() - MAX_PAYLOAD_LENGTH) + " characters]";
        }
        log.info("Request: " + requestBody);


        // process response body logging
        log.info("Time Taken: {}ms", timeTaken);
        log.info("***************************************************");
    }
    responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {         
    return request.getRequestURI().matches("csv");      }

}
```

Comment: The implementation you show above, it limits "batches" to 10,000 records.  Does this version work?  Or does it throw the exception you show in your question?

Comment: I would say its slightly better than not batching it up, but it triggers the exception shown. Batching it up solved my heap out of memory issue for the db ResultSet but now my bottleneck is this

Comment: The problem seems to be that the destination is `ContentCachingResponseWrapper$ResponseServletOutputStream`, that will store the entire response in memory before sending it to its final destination.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for the comment. Do you have any idea which alternative wrapper I could use? When i tried not wrapping it I received a 
`No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/csv'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException`. Technically this should not happen because we have added the message converter in another custom configuration which should not be affected by ContentCachingResponseWrapper. Would really appreciate your help

Comment: You're not showing the - I assume - filter that adds that `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, so I can't really help with that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 
`@Override protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException { ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request); ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);` I tried to exclude this api from the filter which gave me a no converter error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details, don't add code in the comments. In any case, also explain what the purpose is of this filter.